# When I update my official web page I want my facebook page to automatically update

Tags: html, facebook

When I update the content of my official, non-Facebook page I want my Facebook page to automatically get the same update. If this is possible how do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

What type of website do you use? Is it Wordpress or any form of blog if so there will be a plugin, whereas if you have coded your website yourself you could either use PHP or a simpler option would be to create an RSS feed and then use something like http://www.facebook.com/RSS.Graffiti to update your Facebook profile